# How do I fix the route for acceptance tests?

Tags: yii2, codeception, acceptance-testing

I am trying to run acceptance tests on the yii2 advanced app. Out of the box the acceptance tests fail. I will just start with the first problem: I think the routes are wrong and I have no idea where to look to fix them. The error for the about page for example says:

```
Can't be on page "/frontend/web/index-test.php/site/about":
"/frontend/web/index-test.php/site/signup"
```

Where did it get this route from?? Of course there is no page there, that route is garbage. i tried putting it in a browser .. nothing .. of course. I would love to step through the testing classes to see what's going on but I can't figure that out either. Anyone have an idea on this? I think if I can get the routes right at least I can get somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

**Updated answer**:
Make sure that you run `php -S localhost:8080`from the project root, and not from the test directory!

I just tried that, and got pretty much the same errors as you do.

---

**Original answer**:

Out of the box, you will need to do a couple of things before the tests can be run.

[yii2-app-advanced tests readme](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced/tree/master/tests)

1. Install Codeception globally.
2. Create test db.
3. Go to `tests/codeception/config`and look at / edit `config.php` (see below)
4. Run migrations: `codeception/bin/yii migrate`
5. Fire up a webserver: `php -S localhost:8080`
6. Navigate to each of the directories in `tests/codeception`that you want to test for - like `frontend`
7. Run `codecept build`
8. Run `codecept run`

It does run and it does succeed out of the box - provided that you haven't changed any code. :)
If you did change some code, then the tests breaks, and you will have to fix it.

---

`tests/codeception/config/config.php`:

```
'components' => [
    'db' => [
        'dsn' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=name_of_test_db',
    ],
```

Edit:
That route looks fine to me, btw. I guess the issue is that you haven't fired up a webserver before engaging the tests.

You might need to fix your document roots, as described here: [Installation Guide](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced/blob/master/docs/guide/start-installation.md#preparing-application)

Comment: I have done all of the above of course, but, thank you for taking the time to go over it again. The one part I have different is that I am using a different web server, I am using MAMP on this machine so what I did was set the PhpBrowser url to the hostname I am using for this project. Is that the part that  is wrong? Anyway, this is why I have  "zeroed in" on trying to figure out this route issue; does it not use the same routes as the regular application?

Comment: It does use the same route as the regular application, except that it uses `index-test.php`instead of `index.php`:)

Comment: Try and undo the setting up of the phpbrowser - it could be that. I just leave that setting alone, as I found that it messes things up.

Comment: Yes, it seems like you have to use suggested config for it to work, though I still have a problem. I started the built in web server in the project root as described. I can go to a browser and get to http://localhost:8080/frontend/web/index-test.php/site/about and it works(!). BUT, for some reason I am still getting the same error: 
    `Can't be on page "/frontend/web/index-test.php/site/about":` 
I can't imagine what it could be now, I feel like I went over everything and still no luck. Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Comment: From which directory are you running the tests that still fails?

Comment: I am in: `/<project_directory>/tests/codeception/frontend` and  I run: `codecept run acceptance`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104064/discussion-between-dataskills-and-jacmoe).

Comment: You did have the right answer, though my mistake which may be helpful to others, was: **I thought I could use my development web server which was already running for the acceptance tests. That doesn't work.** You cannot do that without more configuration, **you must use the built in webserver described in the instructions**. So, in number 5 in the answer you might say: "Fire up _this_ web server:"